# How to get progressbar when file upload to browser

Tags: reactjs

How to get file uploading percentage when file uploading from client file system to client's browser.

I have the simplest form. I need to get file uploading percentage and show it to user when he upload file.

```
export default function App() {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("submit");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="click to submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-forest-1o1z6?file=/src/App.js:24-336)

Comment: it would need your `post` call HTTP response, to show or hide

Comment: @AshishKamble without calling http request, it's impossible?

Comment: Not possible without getting a response from the server, since the browser does not know how much the file has been uploaded.

Comment: @Terry okay, then post an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is small example, with `react bootsttrap` you can try,
you have to import,

```
import { Container, Row, Col, Form, Button, ProgressBar } from "react-bootstrap"
```

your javascript logic will be like this, `ProgressBar`  needs % percentage value, you can calculate that,

```
const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState()
const [progress, setProgress] = useState()

const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault() //prevent the form from submitting
  let formData = new FormData()

  formData.append("file", selectedFiles[0])

  const axios = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/",
  })

  axios.post("/upload_file", formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
    onUploadProgress: data => {
      //Set the progress value to show the progress bar
      setProgress(Math.round((100 * data.loaded) / data.total))
    },
  })
}
```

here is component return will look like,

```
<Form
  action="http://localhost:8081/upload_file"
  method="post"
  encType="multipart/form-data"
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
>
  <Form.Group>
    <Form.File
      label="Select a File"
      onChange={e => {
        setSelectedFiles(e.target.files)
      }}
    />
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group>
    <Button variant="info" type="submit">
      Upload A File
    </Button>
  </Form.Group>
  {progress && <ProgressBar now={progress} label={`${progress}%`} />}
</Form>
```

Comment: Where is the demo? Any link to sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/intelligent-cache-mxdj4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark